# Setting default font size in quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, quantikz

How do I change the default font size of all text inside a [quantikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz) environment? There isn't anything in the docs.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}%[style={font size=\large}]%[fontsize=\large]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw        & \gate[5, nwires=3]{U_f} & \qw        & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw \rstick[wires=4]{} \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           &           & |[meter]| \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{-}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quantikz` is `tikz`-based and therefore `font=<font settings>` can be used:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}[font=\large]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw        & \gate[5, nwires=3]{U_f} & \qw        & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw \rstick[wires=4]{} \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           &           & |[meter]| \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{-}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw 
\end{quantikz}

\begin{quantikz}[font=\tiny]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw        & \gate[5, nwires=3]{U_f} & \qw        & \gate[4, nwires=3]{H^{\otimes n}} & \qw \rstick[wires=4]{} \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           & \lstick{$\vdots$} &           &           & |[meter]| \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw \\[-10pt]
\lstick{\ket{-}} & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw        & \qw 
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]